# Overhead of direct mapping all physical memory in kernel virtual address space

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

According to https://docs.kernel.org/arch/x86/x86_64/mm.html, let's say 4-level paging, there's a direct mapping of all physical memory, so:

1. Does kernel map all these into kernel page table? Does kernel finish it at boot time?
2. 4-level paging handles a max of 64TB physical memory, if a PTE is 64bit, that's 64TB/4KB*64bit = 128G space only for PTEs, is that a huge overhead? Or kernel uses huge page for this?
3. separate question: does linux kernel use a separate page table or put it together with user page table? Some OS will be like that for avoiding switching page tables (and flush TLB) when syscall.

Comment: 4 level uses only 48 bits, hence you caclucations are wrong. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bydJ0DspzaM

Comment: Additional comment: You don't need a page table that can access all the physical or  virtual memory. That is the reason for multilevel page tables.

Comment: Is that the same thing with huge page?